# Specifying example swagger queries other than curl

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

In all implementations of swagger API documentation I have seen, the only query example format seems to be curl, as in this screenshot:

[image: swagger curl query]

Is it possible to specify other language formats, as per API docs using readme.io etc., in this screenshot:

[image: readme.io query options]

Comment: Were you able to resolve this @KoreMike ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since swagger is open source, you can modify it as per your requirement.

It comes bundled with CURL, but you are free to change the code and use what you deem fit, just be sure to give proper attribution to the original creators of Swagger.

For your specific requirement, you should make changes to the javascript files `swagger-ui` and `swagger-ui-min`

Comment: Thank you @Samapada it's good to know the possibility is there. My problem is that I am not a coder, so would not be able to customise it myself, but it's good to know that it is possible